# Java Modifying a Class Directly, null Reference?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, null

I am new to using Java's new CLASS_NAME() { STUFF } feature, but what I have come across seems strange.
Consider the following code:

```
class Test
{
    public String a;
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String j = "abc";
        //Emulating passing an argument as I did in my code.//
        final String s = j;
        Test v = new Test();
        v.a = s;
        Test e = new Test() {
            public String a = s;
        };
        Test g = new Test();
        g.a = s;
        System.out.println( v.a );
        System.out.println( e.a );
        System.out.println( g.a );
    }
}
```

I would think the output of this program would be:

```
abc

abc

abc
```

Instead it is:

```
abc

null

abc
```

I am really confused as to why this is.
I self taught myself this feature, so I really don't know much about it.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[These are called anonymous classes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Polymorphism doesn't apply to fields. When you do

```
System.out.println( e.a );
```

the field `a` is being resolved on the declared/static type of `e` which is `Test`. And since you haven't explicitly initialized it, it defaults to `null`.

Your declaration a field called `a` in the anonymous class

```
Test e = new Test() {
     public String a = s;
};
```

is `hiding` the field of the same name in its parent class.

You could instead use an initialization block

```
Test e = new Test() {
    {
        a = s;
    }
};
```

since the field is accessible to the sub-classes.